# R shiny render UI does not work

Tags: r, shiny

In my application, I ask the user to input a file (.csv). Further there are two selectInput(s) which are populated with column names from the input file using renderUI(). As user selects two different columns and click submitButton a plot is generated. The UI with ideal output is given below. This works because i have manually input the values in plot and it does not take the columns as selected in drop down options.

**correct output**

[image]

I think the problem is converting *factor* type elements in dataframe to *numeric* type which can be plotted.

**the error image :**

[image]

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 lastgang <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$file)){return()} 
  read.table(file=input$file$datapath, header =TRUE, sep=",") 
})

output$X = renderUI({ 
    selectInput("X", "Select field to plot along X axis", names(lastgang()), selected = NULL)
})

output$Y = renderUI({ 
    selectInput("Y", "Select field to plot along Y axis", names(lastgang()), selected = NULL)
})

output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
   if (is.null(input$X) || is.null(input$Y)){return()} 
   x = input$X
   y = input$Y
   plot(as.numeric(lastgang()$x),as.numeric(lastgang()$y))    
  })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
   library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

 titlePanel("Source Design"),
 sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(fileInput("file", label = h4("Select *.csv file")),

             uiOutput("X"),
             uiOutput("Y"),
             submitButton("Plot")
),

mainPanel(
  plotOutput('plot')  )
)
))
```

Comment: Hard to tell while having no glue how your data looks like. I agree the conversion `as.numeric` probably produces a vector which only consists of `NA` entries. What kind of data do you have? Edit: I saw you call `x <- input$X` and afterwards you are calling `lastgang()$x`. That ought to be only `x`, or not? Otherwise the assignment `x <- input$X` makes no sense I think. Unfortunately I have no experience with `shiny`...

Comment: `x = input$X` will return a column/element name. To get the series of values under that column i am calling lastgang()$x  where lastgang() is bascially a R dataframe converted from .csv file. Further i checked that both columns that i have selected are of type `num` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `x` and `y` are strings and `lastgang` is a dataframe. Then your error does not have any to do with the use of `shiny`. 
The following do not work in `R`

```
> D <- data.frame(Col1=1:5, Col2=11:15)
> a <- 'Col1'
> b <- D$a
> b
NULL
```

This is because after `$` R expects a column name of the data frame. If the variable before `$` is a data frame, then  you got `NULL` if the column name does not exist.
You want the column called `Col1`

```
> D <- data.frame(Col1=1:5, Col2=11:15)
> a <- 'Col1'
> b <- D[, which(names(D) == a)]
> b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Indeed! you are right. I forgot the basic doing the "shinier" stuff. Happens, thanks a lot. This works : `plot(lastgang()[,input$X],lastgang()[, input$Y])`